# Setting width, height of TextBlock behind code for variablesizedwrapgrid not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I need some help confirming I'm seeing a bug.

I am creating a "TagCloud" in xaml for metro. Nothing complex, it should be simple.

I create `TextBlock` objects in the code behind and then add them to the children of a `VariableSizedWrapGrid`

Each `TextBlock` is a different height and width - and this is determined by the `testblock.Measure(size)`, then setting the width and height via `DesiredSize.Width` and `DesiredSize.Height`

```
testblock.Measure(new Size(10000, 250));
        dWidth = Double.Parse(testblock.DesiredSize.Width.ToString());
        dHeight = Double.Parse(testblock.DesiredSize.Height.ToString());
```

The problem is, when the `TextBlock` objects are added they basically clip, they all lock to one single size (basically the behavior of a `WrapGrid`). Essentially the `VariableSizedWrapGrid` is refusing to allow variable heights and widths within its child elements?  I have no idea why it clips everything.

```
<VariableSizedWrapGrid x:Name="vswg" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" Height="200" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

---

```
IEnumerable<TextBlock> textBlocks = 
    (from cloudItem in cloudItems 
     select ConvertToTextBlock(cloudItem, fontWeight));

vswg.Children.Clear();

foreach (TextBlock t in textBlocks)
{
    vswg.Children.Add(t);
}
```

The `ConvertToTextBlock()` returns a new `TextBlock` with a different text and FontSize

I cannot get the `VariableSizedWrapGrid` to actually have a "variable sized" child control. Perhaps I am just using this all wrong?

Comment: You could try to port wrap panel from Silverlight toolkit to WinRT.

Comment: @ToddMain, so just to simplify, you just want a tag cloud you can feed with an itemsource and assign a different font size to each item?

Answer (score 4):

**Try Something like this:**

```
 <GroupStyle.Panel> <ItemsPanelTemplate > <VariableSizedWrapGrid x:Name="MyGrid" Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="7"

ItemWidth="{Binding DataContext.ItemTemplateWidth, ElementName=pageRoot}"

ItemHeight="{Binding DataContext.ItemTemplateHeight, ElementName=pageRoot}"

></VariableSizedWrapGrid> </ItemsPanelTemplate> </GroupStyle.Panel>
```

***Also consider reading:***

1. http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2012/09/14/windows-8-xaml-and-displaying-multiple-sized-items.aspx
2. http://www.acnenomor.com/3756161p1/how-to-display-gridview-items-with-variable-width-in-window-8

Answer (score 1):

Try considering using DataTemplate.

VariableSizedWrapGrid provid ItemHeight and ItemWidth properties. Then, you can only choose the Width and Height of an item "in cells". So, you can choose your item to fit 3 cells width and 1 cell height.

You should consider reading: http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/03/07/Databinding-to-the-VariableSizedWrapGrid-in-Windows-8-Metro.aspx

Comment: i have checked this solution before...

the issue is the columnspan {binding width} is undefined variable... the text that is displayed in the "cloudtag" could be of any undefined length - as the fontsize can be variable by "count", this isnt really practical.  this works (if you define the a fixed columnspan), but i wanted to treat the wrapgrid as if it were a wpf wrappanel, just drop a control onto it, and then drop another next to it - no alignment, no size adjustments etc.  im just going to pen this one down to another winrt limitation.  just like style.triggers (which i really want back)

Comment: using an unsetted width is not a good practice: you will loose the "Virutal" property of the VariableSizedWrapGrid. Prevent having your width defined items. It's too long for rendering if you have many items.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
DesiredSize.Width.ToString()
```

To this:

```
Width.ToString()
```

The layout system is a complex three pass process, when you allow the "DesiredSize" value to be controlled by saying "DesiredSize in the code" the layout system takes charge.  When you specify a width the layout system is overridden.